# How to get a gradient node with mxnet.jl and Julia?

Tags: julia, gradient-descent, mxnet, mxnet.jl

I'm trying to replicate the following example from the mxnet main docs with mxnet.jl in Julia:

```
A = Variable('A')
B = Variable('B')
C = B * A
D = C + Constant(1)
# get gradient node.
gA, gB = D.grad(wrt=[A, B])
# compiles the gradient function.
f = compile([gA, gB])
grad_a, grad_b = f(A=np.ones(10), B=np.ones(10)*2)
```

The example shows how to autodiff a symoblic expression and obtain its gradients.

What is the equivalent in mxnet.jl (latest version 2016-03-07)?

Answer (score 1):

Code in `MXNet.jl/src/symbolic-node.jl` may be helpful for you to find answers.

I am not familiar with this package.
Here is my Guess:

    `A = mx.Variable("A")
    B = mx.Variable("B")
    C = B .* A
    D = C + 1`

`mx.normalized_gradient` may be the solution to the remaining part if exists.